# Spark: How to save a dataframe with headers?

Tags: java, apache-spark

`dataframe.saveasTextFile`, saves only the data in a delimited format. How do I save the dataframe with headers in JAVA.

```
sourceRufFrame.toJavaRDD().map(new TildaDelimiter()).coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(targetSrcFilePath);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to save as csv file, i would suggest using `spark-csv` package. You can save your dataframe simply with `spark-csv` as below with header.

```
dataFrame.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter",<your delimiter>)
  .save(output)
```

You can refer below link, for further information:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

`Spark-csv` has maven dependency.

Answer (score 16):

With Spark 2.x,

```
df.write.option("header", "true").csv("path")
```

Cheers

Comment: doesnt write headers if df has no records